# How to extend Cookie expiry from user's last activity?

Tags: cookies, extend

How to extend cookie expiry date from last activity which user has done?

Lets take an example, by default, cookie is set for 30minutes after user login.
userA do login at 1PM, hence given cookie will expire at 1.30PM.

Problem with this scenario is that if userA is doing something very important activity in app, then when he click on submit form on any internal link, he will get redirected to login.
Hence he loses his work which he as done.

What I want to have is when userA log in at 1PM (First activity), then at first, cookie will expire at 1.30PM.
After that userA become idle, that means he does not click anywhere, he just leave his computer and come back again after 15 minutes i.e. at 1.15PM and starts using php portal, then cookie expiry should become 1.45PM

How to do that? I found script PHPmyadmin has done same thing. It leads to expiration of cookie when user become inactive for more that 1440 seconds.

Comment: You have to depend on JavaScript to trigger mouse moves, and then, send active or idle flag through ajax to the server, then, update the cookie. Why you expire cookie for 30 minutes? only depend on idle time if greater than (10 minutes or as you decide) and when the page closed.